# Trying to ease a click event on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this webpage where I zoom in a SVG to a specific area (the lighter rectangle). The way I do that is by changing the viewBox attribute because there is a bigger element in the svg (now it's just the red rectangle), and I prefer not to use libraries.

So, everything works but the zoom function happens too quick, I am wondering how to slow it as it was a transition in CSS. I don't now if I have to relate the js script with CSS or if my transition attemp is in the wrong place.

```js
     
     var selected = false;
     var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
     var rect =document.getElementById('rect');

     var zoomOnElement = function(e) {
          if (e.target === selected) 

          {
       // Deselect element
       //svg.setAttribute("viewBox","264.5 126.2 1149.9 547.4");
       selected = false;
          }
           else  
           {
       // Select element
       selected = e.target;
       var viewBox = selected.getAttribute('x')
        viewBox += " " + selected.getAttribute('y')
        viewBox += " " + (selected.getAttribute('width'))
        viewBox += " " + (selected.getAttribute('height'))
       svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);}
      }

     document.getElementById('window').addEventListener("click", zoomOnElement);
```

```css
      html {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
      body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}

      svg {
       height:100vh;
       width: 100vw;
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
       position: absolute;
       -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
       transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      }

      div {
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
       float: left;
       position: absolute;
      }

      rect.mouse:hover {
       cursor: pointer;
      }

      .box{
       width: 98.7;
       height: 70;
      }
```

```html
     <svg version="1.1" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="264.5 126.2 1149.9 547.4" xml:space="preserve">


    <rect x="263.3" y="126.7" opacity="0.39" fill="#370B13" width="1149.8" height="547.6"/>
    <rect  id="rect" x="739.8" y="298.6" opacity="0.4" fill="#F7F7F7" width="62.9" height="70"/>
    <rect class="mouse" id="window" x="729.8" y="292.3" opacity="0.8" fill="#F7F7F7" width="157.2" height="83"/>
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" points="750.9,298.6 738.7,298.6 738.7,368.6 750.9,368.6 "/>
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" points="794.8,368.6 802.8,368.6 802.8,298.6 794.8,298.6 "/>
    </svg>

    <div id="left" class="half"></div>
```

Comment: FYI: `document.getElementById('window').addEventListener("click", zoomOnElement);` can just be `addEventListener("click", zoomOnElement);` since `window` is the Global object in a browser environment.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) isn't working because when you click your SVG, you aren't changing any CSS properties. Transition is only for when a CSS property undergoes a change. All you really need to do is change the CSS [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) to create a zoom effect.

```css
/* This style will be applied when the SVG is clicked */
.zoomed { transform:scale(2.0); }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

 <style type="text/css">
  html {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
  body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}

  svg {
   height:100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   position: absolute;
      transform:scale(1.0); /* Set the initial zoom */
   transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  }
      
  div {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
  }

  rect.mouse:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  .box{
   width: 98.7;
   height: 70;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <svg version="1.1" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="264.5 126.2 1149.9 547.4" xml:space="preserve">
   <rect x="263.3" y="126.7" opacity="0.39" fill="#370B13" width="1149.8" height="547.6"/>
   <rect  id="rect" x="739.8" y="298.6" opacity="0.4" fill="#F7F7F7" width="62.9" height="70"/>
   <rect class="mouse" id="window" x="729.8" y="292.3" opacity="0.8" fill="#F7F7F7" width="157.2" height="83"/>
   <polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" points="750.9,298.6 738.7,298.6 738.7,368.6 750.9,368.6 "/>
   <polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" points="794.8,368.6 802.8,368.6 802.8,298.6 794.8,298.6 "/>
</svg>

<div id="left" class="half"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
  svg.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Dynamically add the .zoomed CSS class, triggering the transition
    this.classList.add("zoomed");
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, thanks, but the purpose of changing the ViewBox size is to fit it on the viewport without calculate translate transitions or scale. Maybe I asked the question in the wrong way, sorry, what I'm trying to smooth is the js function. By the way, I need the window id because that rectangle is the area I want to be clicked on.

Comment: @erikufli You can change the ViewBox size as well if you like, but the point is that CSS Transitions only work when modifying CSS properties (which is what your question was asking about). And, you don't need to specify `window` with `.addEventListener()` and it will still work exactly the same way because `window` is the browser's Global object - - it's implied when it's not explicitly stated. Just like when we say `alert()` instead of `window.alert()`.